# Interface Builder: in ios 5, window object hides view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, interface-builder

This problem is not a big deal, still I'm curious as to why it happens and I can't find much on the Apple's developer area.

Basically, I have a simple app whose MainWindow contains a UITabBarController. The NIB in Interface Builder was auto generated initially, with a "window" object.

If I try this setting with iOS6 it works fine on any device.

If I try this with iOS5, the window object is opaque and hides everything (i.e. white screen on start).

Clearly, if I set the background as transparent, it shows what's behind. I've tried placing the window way down in the Objects list, but that didn't help.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code? sounds like a strange behavior

Comment: Hi @perrohunter - the question is "the code of what?" :) The app delegate (where I make no such setting other than   `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`), any of the underlying view controllers? From what I can see, it seems a problem in the XIB, rather than in the code.